# Why does the expiration date of the request cache lie in the past?

Tags: firefox, caching, firebug

I am working on caching some pages and I noticed this in Firebug:

[image: Cache expiration date lying in the past]

So it says that the cache expired 45 years ago. Is this a bug or some bad data?

I have another page that is caching correctly

[image: Correct cache expiration date]

I just do not understand why its saying `Expires ... 1970`. This page won't cache at all on my site, even though I'm using the Boost module with Drupal.

Comment: Yes. You're not setting the date properly when setting the cache expiry -- and instead setting it to 0. So it defaults to the start of the epoch (01.01.1970)

Comment: Unix time (also known as POSIX time or erroneously as Epoch time) is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds. (wiki)

Comment: This date is shown if no explicite Expires is set in your application. That means that the page should never cached.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Ah I see so this means that even with boost these pages will not cache because something on my site is specifying that these should never be cached.
Thanks guys, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Expires` header is set to `0`, the browser interprets it as 1 January 1970, which relates to the [Unix time aka POSIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Because this date lies in the past, this means that the request is not cached.

The `Expires` header is [defined within RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3), which includes this paragraph related to the statement above:

> A cache recipient MUST interpret invalid date formats, especially the value "0", as representing a time in the past (i.e., "already expired").